# Azure table query performance with partition key, rowkey and non-index

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I have a table query below that search by PK, RK and a non-index key.

Will this slow down database search? Will the search by DOB be faster if it performs on web layer via c#?

```
        var name = "John";
        var wins = 20;
        var dob = DateTimeOffset.Parse("1999-1-1");
        string usernameFilter2 =
            TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, name),
                        TableOperators.And,
                        TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForInt("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, wins)), 
                TableOperators.And,
                TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("DateOfBirth", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, dob));
```

Comment: I’m not sure if your query will return any results because you’re doing an “and” query using partition key and two row keys. Is there a typo in your query?

Comment: a type. thx for poiting it out

Comment: My answer still remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering there can be a single entity for a PartitionKey/RowKey combination, I believe your query's 3rd filter criteria is redundant (assuming you've meant to include another attribute there instead of RowKey).

As far as the speed of the query goes, again considering you're searching for an entity with matching PartitionKey and RowKey, this query will be the fastest. If you remove RowKey from your query and search on PartitionKey and any other non-indexed attribute, it will be slower as the query will be doing a partition scan to find a matching entity.

You may find this article helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide.

Comment: I meant it is slower adding DateOfBirth property in the query? But it is still better to add the filter in web layer?

Comment: Only if you exclude RowKey from the query. If you add RowKey in your query then you don’t need to add this DateOfBirth filter. Not sure I understand your 2nd question.

Comment: Adding DateOfBirth is to further filter out result when PK and RK are matched. Thus, DateOfBirth is required.

Comment: There can only be one entity matching a PK/RK combination.

Comment: DateOfBirth  should be ValidDate or similar. The ideal is that even both PK/RK are matched, if the ValidDate has expired, the row is not returned. This is why the ValidDate is used. If you check the query statement, replace DateOfBirth  with ValidDate, it might make sense. In this case, using ValidDate in the query might slow down a bit, but not noticable?

Comment: Makes sense. In my experience there shouldn’t be any slowness in your query. You would either get exactly one result or zero result.